Using ChatGPT or similar for helping lean programming
ChatGPT is a great help for programming in standard programming languages. It does not seem to be as good with lean, a program for formalizing mathematical proofs. Is it possible to make it (1) refer to the current version of lean (2) know about the mathematical library available for lean. One problem is that these requirements form a moving target, since the language is in rapid development.
I'm new to lean, and it's possible that what I'm asking for already exists in some form. If it does, please tell me where I can find out about that.

In ChatGPT, you can create your own GPT models by uploading current documents and other sources of information, but this requires a monthly subscription. Another way to leverage the current information on lean programming is by building a Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) system. This approach requires ChatGPT's API key and is charged based on the tokens used (1 word ≈ 1.3 tokens). Essentially, this is what ChatGPT offers to Plus members.
A zero-cost option is to use few-shot prompting to describe your function and then generate text based on that. There is an open-source add-on for Copilot named Leanpilot, which uses the ChatGPT API key for suggestions.
